# Dark scab/wound on cat’s nose bridge

Tags: cats, injury

We haven’t gotten the cat as it’s newly purchased but it’s gotten this new scab over the past week in the pet shop. The owners are unsure as to what it is and how she got it as well.

She lives alone in a plastic cubicle, so it can’t be from other cats or the cage itself. The wound does not seem to hurt to touch. Anyone has any idea what it could be and whether it’ll leave a permanent scar?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A tiny scratch like that can happen when your kitten plays or scratches herself and is nothing to worry about; it will heal on its own and is unlikely to leave any visible scar.

It might take some time until the area is covered by fur again but this depends on the growth cycles of your cat`s hair; you can find more information about this here: https://animalpath.org/how-fast-does-cat-hair-grow/